# Solving the recurrence T(n) = T(n/3) + O(logn) + n by giving a tight bound

Tags: algorithm, discrete-mathematics, recurrence

Is it ok to drop the lower terms when solving recurrences, like in this case I decided to drop the O(logn).

please excuse the bad hand writing!
Here is my attempt at solving the recurrence:

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/4G3ZMbY

Comment: I'm sorry this is my attemp ^^^^

Answer (score 0):

You can rewrite `O(log n) + n = Theta(n)` and continue on your merry way with the Master Theorem to get a bound of `Theta(n)`.

If you want an even better bound, you can go to the trouble of verifying `T(n) = 3n/2 + c log^2 n` for some fixed constant `c` using the substitution method.